# Inject scripts and styles define in a parent to an iframe

Tags: reactjs, next.js, vite, react-frame-component

I'm building a component library/css framework, and I want to demo it in an iframe to isolate the style from the page. My setup is a monorepo of Next.js (documentation/where I want to demo) and Vite.js (for the library code).

For rendering the `iframe` I'm using [`react-frame-component`](https://github.com/ryanseddon/react-frame-component).

I have an entry script file like this for the library:

```
// vite-repo, loads all the styling:
import './index.scss'

// 
function init() {
}

init()
```

then in react-components/pages I can import it like this:

```
// documentation/demo page
import Frame from 'react-frame-component'
import 'vite-repo' // loads the style of lib and executes the init function, want to do this on the iframe instead.

return Page() {
  // need to inject the styles and js to iframe (react-frame-component).
  <Frame>
  </Frame>
}
```

Any idea how can I do this?
Building the library then importing them like this works, but I want to be able to do this on dev too (no access yet to the build bundle).

```
// documentation/demo page
return Page() {
  // Inject the styles and js to the iframe.
  <Frame head={
  <script src="/library.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/library.min.css"></link>
  }>
  </Frame>
}
```

Comment: Could you provide a reproduction of your monorepo configuration?

Answer (score 1):

You could change your dev command in the library code to build the production bundle when the library code changes

https://vitejs.dev/guide/build.html#rebuild-on-files-changes

```
vite build --watch
```

Answer (score 1):

May I suggest changing things up a little. From what I understand you have your library code, and then you have some dev playground and docs site (the NextJS app). Keeping your library code seperate is a good design decision.

Your setup should look something like this.

```html
<!-- file: component-library/src/index.html -->

<html>
 ...
 <script src="/main.js" /> <!--  the entrypoint to your library -->
</html>
```

> will note here, that the `main.js` (where you currently have your `init` function) should be for your dev-time playground, use something like `index.js` for your consumers to import.

```
// file: nextjs/app/routes/demo.jsx

// Note; you don't need `react-frame-component` your sandboxed vite app can handle that part.

function DemoPage() {
   return <iframe src="http://localhost:3000"></iframe>;
}

export default DemoPage;
```

Done , now all you need is to run the nextjs app as you'd normally do;

```bash
npm run dev # or whatever start command you have
```

and then run your demo app in a seperate terminal;

```bash
vite --port 3000
```

> or as a single command `vite --port 3000 & next dev` (`&` so they run concurrently)

and there you go, you should have the site app running in a sandbox/iframe away form your nextjs app.